# How do you filter null values from an image collection when reducing so they are not considered in the calculation of mean, sum etc.?

Tags: google-earth-engine

How do you filter null values when reducing image collections so they are not considered in the calculation of standard deviation, mean, sum etc.?
I have tried the following for the image collection.

```
var ColG = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([ee.Image(Part1),
      ee.Image(Part2),ee.Image(Part3),ee.Image(Part4),
      ee.Image(Part5),ee.Image(Part6),ee.Image(Part7),ee.Image(Part8)]);
var mG = ColG.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(properties)).mean();
```

I have also tried the following for individual images first. But neither works.

```
//#2013
var mask1 = Part1.eq(0);
var Part1_m = Part1.updateMask(mask1);
//#2014
var mask2 = Part2.eq(0);
var Part2_m = Part2.updateMask(mask2);
//#2015
var mask3 = Part3.eq(0);
var Part3_m = Part3.updateMask(mask3);
//#2016
var mask4 = Part4.eq(0);
var Part4_m = Part4.updateMask(mask4);
//#2017
var mask5 = Part5.eq(0);
var Part5_m = Part5.updateMask(mask5);
//#2018
var mask6 = Part6.eq(0);
var Part6_m = Part6.updateMask(mask6);
//#2019
var mask7 = Part7.eq(0);
var Part7_m = Part7.updateMask(mask7);
//#2020
var mask8 = Part8.eq(0);
var Part8_m = Part8.updateMask(mask8);
//Create an image collection of adjusted modeled grain yield (GY) 
var ColG = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([ee.Image(Part1_m),
      ee.Image(Part2_m),ee.Image(Part3_m),ee.Image(Part4_m),
      ee.Image(Part5_m),ee.Image(Part6_m),ee.Image(Part7_m),ee.Image(Part8_m)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Image pixels can't contain null values, so your question doesn't quite make sense.

If you have a specific no-data value (looks like you think 0 means no data), then the masking you did in the second example is almost right except you want .neq() instead of .eq().

Masked pixels aren't included in the calculation in normal reductions.